# Knockout: change event binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel with different pages. On the landing page I created a dropdown (html select form) that contains a selection other than the page options. I'd like to switch to the 'Dashboard-page' page, once an option in the dropdown is selected.

Right now I use an EventListener in the js but was wondering whether I could simplify it by using a knockout event-binding within the dropdown (i prepared an event line in the html code).

Here is my current code:

```js
const availableComponents = ['Header', 'Footer']
const availablePages = ['LandingPage', 'Dashboard', 'About']
const setPage = pageName => {
            const newPage = availablePages.find(p => p === pageName);
            if (newPage) activePage(newPage);
        };
const activePage = ko.observable(availablePages[0]);
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.page-selector');

ko.applyBindings(window.vm);

selectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
setPage('Dashboard')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js" integrity="sha512-vs7+jbztHoMto5Yd/yinM4/y2DOkPLt0fATcN+j+G4ANY2z4faIzZIOMkpBmWdcxt+596FemCh9M18NUJTZwvw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<label>
  Choose a Component:
  <select class="page-selector" data-bind="
        options: availableComponents
         optionsCaption: 'Select Component',
        event: //add event-binding here
  ">
  </select>
</label>  
 <p> Selected Page: <span data-bind="text: activePage"></span>
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern:

```js
const availableComponents = ['Header', 'Footer']
const availablePages = ['LandingPage', 'Dashboard', 'About']
const setPage = pageName => {
            const newPage = availablePages.find(p => p === pageName);
            if (newPage) activePage(newPage);
        };
const activePage = ko.observable(availablePages[0]);
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.page-selector');

ko.applyBindings(window.vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js" integrity="sha512-vs7+jbztHoMto5Yd/yinM4/y2DOkPLt0fATcN+j+G4ANY2z4faIzZIOMkpBmWdcxt+596FemCh9M18NUJTZwvw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<label>
  Choose a Component:
  <select class="page-selector" data-bind="
        options: availableComponents
         optionsCaption: 'Select Component',
        event: {change: () => {
                setPage('Dashboard')
                }}
  ">
  </select>
</label>  
 <p> Selected Page: <span data-bind="text: activePage"></span>
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your event change, call function probably works its not how a KO vm is meant to work. I'd use a Value binding observable on the page-selector binding, with a 2 way observable to your viewmodel property "selectedPage".

The use a subscribe on that observable

```
pageViewModel.selectedPage.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   setPage(newValue)
});
```

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html